# I am trying to change the style of a html link with javascript functions. Why does my code not work?

Tags: javascript, html

In the console I get these types of errors:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
>
> ReferenceError: changeButtonOnMouseOver is not defined

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<script>
    function changeButtonOnMouseOver()
    {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.background-color = "#00806f";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
    function changeButtonOnClick()
    {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.box-shadow = "none";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.top = "5px";
    }
    function changeButtonOnMouseOut()
    {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.border-radius = "15px";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.background-color = "#009682";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.box-shadow = "0 5px 0 #00332c";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.cursor = "auto";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.padding = "1em 1.5em";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.position = "relative";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.text-align = "center";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.text-decoration = "none";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.font-size = "x-large";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.font-weight = "800";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.outline = "none";
        document.getElementById("btn").style.border = "none";
    }
</script>

<a id="btn" href="#" onmouseover="changeButtonOnMouseOver()" onclick="changeButtonOnClick()" onmouseout="changeButtonOnMouseOut()"

style="border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #009682;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 800;
  outline: none;
  border: none;" >

  Zur Anmeldung</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I made the link look like a button and I want to change the style with javascript functions for onmouseover or onclick events so it looks like you press a button when you click the link but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use camelCase property name in JavaScript......

Comment: Have you considered using CSS, using the anchors states?
`:hover`, `:focus` and `:active` for example.

Comment: @wbarton I can't use CSS. I can online modify the style inline or through JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You should use camelCase property name for style in JavaScript:

```js
function changeButtonOnMouseOver(){
  document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "#00806f";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.cursor = "pointer";
}
function changeButtonOnClick(){
  document.getElementById("btn").style.boxShadow = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.top = "5px";
}
function changeButtonOnMouseOut(){
  document.getElementById("btn").style.borderRadius = "15px";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "#009682";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.boxShadow = "0 5px 0 #00332c";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.color = "white";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.cursor = "auto";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.padding = "1em 1.5em";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.position = "relative";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.textDecoration = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.fontSize = "x-large";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.fontWeight = "800";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.outline = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.border = "none";
}
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#" onmouseover="changeButtonOnMouseOver()" onclick="changeButtonOnClick()" onmouseout="changeButtonOnMouseOut()" style="border-radius: 15px;background-color: #009682;box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;color: white;padding: 1em 1.5em;position: relative;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-size: x-large;font-weight: 800;outline: none;border: none;">Zur Anmeldung</a>
```

You can achieve the same with pure CSS:

```js
function changeButtonOnClick(){
  document.getElementById("btn").style.boxShadow = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn").style.top = "5px";
}
```

```css
#btn, #btn:not(:hover){
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #009682;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 800;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
#btn:hover{
  background-color: #00806f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn:not( :hover ){ 
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #009682;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 800;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#" onclick="changeButtonOnClick()" >
Zur Anmeldung</a>
```

Comment: I can't use classes so I can't use:
    #btn{
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-color: #009682;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;
      color: white;
      padding: 1em 1.5em;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: x-large;
      font-weight: 800;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }

Comment: Adding the initial style inline already works. What doesn't work is changing it with JavaScript functions for events.

Comment: @kachris, the first solution in the answer shows that it is working using JavaScript....

Answer (score 0):

You should camelCase for properties of `style`. Just remove `-` and make letter after `-` upperCase e.g `background-color => backgroundColor`. It will be same for for `-`. For example:

```
background-color => backgroundColor
border-left-width => borderLeftWidth
```

See [**An aside on variable naming rules**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#An_aside_on_variable_naming_rules).

> You can call a variable pretty much anything you like, but there are limitations. Generally, you should stick to just using Latin characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z) and the underscore character
>   
>   You **shouldn't use other characters** because they may cause errors or be hard to understand for an international audience

Comment: I already changed the JavaScript part. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is loaded, before the id btn even exists in the DOM. You should put your script after declaring the id or set your script to be loaded after the DOM isnfully build

Comment: I tried both putting the script part before and after the link. Both options don't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot add/edit the CSS and use classes. Can you create a new `style` node containing the required styles with JS?

```js
const styleNode = document.createElement('style');
styleNode.type = 'text/css';

const cssStyles = `
#btn {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #009682;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #00332c;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 800;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
#btn:hover{
    background-color: #00806f;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#btn:active {
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 5px;
}
`;

styleNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssStyles));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#">Zur Anmeldung</a>
```